# How to take substring

Tags: postgresql

I have a list, and I need to take only first words including numbers of every row without anything after numbers. How can I achieve that?
[A pic is provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9elV.png)

For example:

I have a row like this:

```
ЛУ 344 ул.Яссауй в районе дома №163 северном направление
```

As a result I want to get:

```
ЛУ 344
```

Left, right won't help because the number of characters can change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) will help.

Or the [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html)

Or the [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)

Depends on the use you want and the way you want to get the substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex based `substring()` variant:

```
substring(the_column from '\w+\s+[0-9]+')
```

This will extract the first "word characters" followed by one or more spaces followed by one or more numbers

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ed2327348e0d19690ca94cd10d26cfd7)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot, but what should I do if I want to take only one word or all words after numbers without the first word. Ex.: ЛУ 344 ул.Яссауй в районе дома №163 северном направление. As a result: 44 ул.Яссауй в районе

Comment: @Bexultan that is an entirely different question. It is likely to have a considerably different answer. You should accept the answer given here, and post a new question.